# Python: check for valid enum

Tags: enums

I have an enum declared:

```
enum Car {
  AVENTADOR = 0
  LIMO = 1
  HUMMER = 2
  TOYOTA = 3
}
```

Then I get FERRARI input from user and store the input in variable called response,
so that response = FERRARI

How do I check whether the variable response is one of the car enum types?
ie: how do I do:

```
#if (response != CarTypes):
```

**NB: I do not want to change enum into a class like I have seen in another post in stackoverflow. I also do not want a hard code solution of the enums (eg: if (response < AVENTADOR || response > TOYOTA) as I might add more enums later on**

Comment: What is enum declaration? It is not Python.

Comment: Ah oops. Sorry about that. (I'm new to python). Do you recommend I delete the above "python" post? That enum stuff is C related and written inside a protobuf...ie: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425502/checking-for-valid-enum-types-from-protobufs.
I was not getting a response to my protobuf stuff so I assumed I will ask it simply in python terms.

Comment: I removed the Python tags.

Comment: Ahm but I want a python solution though...

Comment: You basically wrote down what you don't want. Do it the other way around and show us what you have tried in Python so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if an Enum member with a certain name exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795488/how-to-test-if-an-enum-member-with-a-certain-name-exists)